# How can I get same id in friends & tagable friends Facebook api?

Tags: android, facebook

We are working on an Application in which we are getting friends data using me/friends & me/taggable_friends apis.

For both of the apis we are getting different id of user. In me/taggable_friends api, It is returning different id of particular user.

Please advice how to manage this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What you get from the `taggable_friends` endpoint is not an id, but a token only – and it is short-lived.

The *only* purpose for which you are supposed to use it, is tagging friends in OG stories. For that, you are supposed to provide the user with a UI where they can select the friends they want to tag.

You are not allowed to try and use the data you get from that endpoint for any other purpose.