# v2.0 facebook graph api not getting user id from graph api via taggable_friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

In v1.0 API I was able to get friends with their facebook ID like this:

```
{
    "id": "757157247693594",
    "name": "Jony Woker"
},
```

In the v2.2 I can use only taggable_friends to get this information, however `i must have missed something in the documentation, because the id I'm getting is like this (id is always different):

```
{
   "id": "AaL5Bh-Kv7YBI1tq9DdERW9f74MK5mpO-yersgJ7RkRQ9THxVgU_3MmU4sJImgMvggjbPKZ_hexxr98of9v4KAwwoziaz9lfU08JwyQxXUGviw",
   "name": "Jony Woker"
}
```

Please advice me how to manage this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: it´s a tagging token, not an id. see tobis answer.

Comment: Looks to me like you did just set up a new account, to ask the same thing asked here yesterday already: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33215129/1427878 (Especially the use of the same phrase “Please advice how to manage this situation” seems like an unlikely coincidence otherwise.)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't miss something. You cannot replace the `/me/friends` edge with `/me/taggable_friends`.

The latter is only to be used to tag friends in posts, not to show the list of friends, and this is intentional.

It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/